# Recursive countdown

Tags: java, recursion

I need to make a method in Java for a recursive countdown where the user enters the `max` and `min` for the countdown.  The print should be in `main`.

This is my code:

```
static void stej(int max, int min) {
    if(max==min)
        System.out.print(min);
    else {
        System.out.print(max + " ");
        stej(max-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, what is the problem?

Comment: You should `stej(max-1, min);` to make your code compiles.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method stej(int, int) in the type *** is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Agree completely.

Comment: And you should verify, before starting, that max >= min

Comment: when i input both the min and max in main, this happens in the console

Comment: what he means is that the line of code that currently reads `stej(max-1)` should read `stej(max-1,min)`. The method stej is declared with two arguments, you must provide two arguments each time it is called.

Comment: okay...just ran out of memory running this code:

Comment: static void stej(int max, int min) {
    if(max==min)
     System.out.print(min);
    else {
     System.out.print(max + " ");
     stej(max-1, min);
    }
 }

Answer (score 1):

There is an argument missing in the recursive call:

```
static void stej(int max, int min) {
    if (max == min) {
        System.out.print(min);
    } else {
        System.out.print(max + " ");
        stej(max - 1, min);
    }
}
```

As for printing in `main`, you can't do that, except if you move all the code to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method has two parameters(max and min) yet you call with only one argument.

```
static void stej(int max, int min) {
    if(max==min)
        System.out.print(min);
    else {
        System.out.print(max + " ");
        stej(max-1, min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues:

- As commenters pointed out you are getting a compile time error because the argument count you're using in the recursive call are different than what's in the method declaration
- The other is you are improperly checking the bounds for limiting the recursion.

The solution below should deal with both issues:

```
static void stej(int max, int min) {
    if (max < min) {        // If the arguments are reversed
        setj(min, max);     // Recursively swap them to continue
    } else {
        System.out.print(max + " ");   // Only need to print once
        if (max > min) {               // Only apply recursion if they are different
            stej(max-1, min);
        }
    }
}
```